# Modifying format of lines in a file via command line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file that contains tab separated dates, of the form: `20160101`. I'd like to modify all lines so that the dates are instead structured like `2016-01-01`. I have been doing this in emacs so far but this is very slow when the files are large and I'd like to see if there is a command line option?

Specifically, the file that currently looks like this:

```
20160101      20160103
20160104      20160107
20160106      20160201
20160201      20160205
20160119      20160122
   ...           ...
```

will become:

```
2016-01-01      2016-01-03
2016-01-04      2016-01-07
2016-01-06      2016-02-01
2016-02-01      2016-02-05
2016-01-19      2016-01-22
   ...           ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/2016\(..\)\(..\)/2016-\1-\2/g' input >output
```

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -r 's/([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/\1-\2-\3/g'
```

Comment: I found that I needed to escape parentheses .. otherwise, your regex is better than mine

Comment: Without `-r`, they need to be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)\([0-9]\{2\}\)/\1-\2-\3/g'
```